# loop through xml-result

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to loop through the results of an httpservice, it is xml.

This is how I try to do it, but this does not work. What am I missing?

```
protected function getArtistsSucces(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        var artistList:XMLList = XMLList(event.result);
        var artistXML:XML;
        for each(artistXML in artistList.artists)
        {
            var artistName:String = artistXML.artist.name;
            var artistPic:String = artistXML.artist.image.(@size=="large");
            insertArtistUrl = "http://localhost:8888/flexapp/insert_artist.php?name=" + artistName + "&pic=" + artistPic
                              + "&userid=" + userId;
            insertArtistService.send();
        }
    }
```

and this is the result in the debugger:

[image: result from debugger]

All nodes:
[image: all nodes]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the xml?

Comment: Create watch expression `artistList.artists` and what result will come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the

```
resultFormat="e4x"
```

to my HTTPService. Adding this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by iterating through `artistList.artists.artist` which would represent the list of `artist` nodes (instead of its parent node).

Answer (score 0):

The code below might fix the problem. But if the problem continues try to trace otu the object you get. I put some trace inline. GL

```
  protected function getArtistsSucces(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        var artistList:XMLList = XMLList(event.result);
        var artistXML:XML;
        for each(artistXML in artistList.artists.artist) 
        // i m not sure about "artistList.artists.artist" here.
        //Cant check it atm, need your xml data.
        {
            //trace(artistXML); // check which object comes here.

            var artistName:String = artistXML.name;
            var artistPic:String = artistXML.image.(@size=="large");
            insertArtistUrl = "http://localhost:8888/flexapp/insert_artist.php?name=" + artistName + "&pic=" + artistPic
                              + "&userid=" + userId;
            insertArtistService.send();
        }
    }
```